# MySQL averaging over many SUM()s that use CASE WHENs -- is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sum, average

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

I have a table with several rows of "speed" per 5-minute block of "time". I want to take the average across 12 of these 5-minute blocks to get an hourly rate of speed. The dummy approach that I've come up with is to calculate a sum for each 5-minute block, and then divide them by 12.

Is there a better way, either in terms of coding simplicity or sql efficiency?

```
SELECT (

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
10 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
5 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) + 

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
15 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
10 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
20 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
15 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
25 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
20 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
30 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
25 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) + 

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
35 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
30 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
40 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
35 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
45 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
40 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
50 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
45 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
55 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
50 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
60 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
55 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END) +

SUM(CASE WHEN time > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
65 MINUTE) AND time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 
60 MINUTE) THEN speed ELSE 0 END)

)/12
FROM table
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(IFNULL(ws.sums, 0))
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 i union all SELECT 2 union all SELECT 3 union all SELECT 4 union all SELECT 5 union all SELECT 6 union all SELECT 7 union all SELECT 8 union all SELECT 9 union all SELECT 10 union all SELECT 11 union all SELECT 12
) windows
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(speed) sums,
         FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, time)) / 300) window
  FROM workers_speeds
  WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, time)) / 60 < 65
  AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, time)) / 60 > 5
  GROUP BY FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, time)) / 300)
) ws on windows.i = ws.window
```

[**Click here to see it in action at SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a68a/21)

*Explanation*

Looking at the bottom inner query first... we need a simple way of identifying each interval. To do this I have used the [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function to get the difference between the `time` column and the current time. This is returned in h:m:s format, so I then pass this to the [`TIME_TO_SEC()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) to convert to seconds. We can now divide by 300 (the number of seconds in 5 minutes) and use the [`FLOOR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) function to round down to the nearest integer. This gives us a kind-of ID for each 5-minute interval ranging from 1 to 12 that we can use to `GROUP BY`. We then include this ID in the `SELECT` and give it the alias `window` and add the `WHERE` & `AND` clauses to ensure we only include data for 1 hour, ignoring the latest 5 minutes.

Now looking at the outer query... I generate a derived table `windows` which contains 12 rows of dummy data, simply the integers 1 to 12. We can then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the inner query also as a derived table `ws` which allows us to ensure there are always 12 rows returned. `ws.sums` will be null where an interval contains no data, but we can use [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to translate that to 0.

I'm not totally sure it will behave exactly as you require, so if you use it, you should make sure you do the necessary testing, especially on the boundaries of the intervals.

Comment: Not quite. Whereas mine returns 189.4167, yours returns 599.1045. I'm not entirely sure why that is, though.

Comment: Also difficult for me to figure out without seeing your data. If you run the inner query, do those sums also look too big?

Comment: This is what it looks like with the SUM()s dumped from each function: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6kKduSEJ

Comment: OK thanks. I had the `TIMEDIFF` params in the wrong order. I've updated my answer. Still get a much higher number though, but it's closer. Will continue to look...

Comment: You want the intervals with 0 to be included in the average calculation?

Comment: Yes they can be included.

Can you explain a bit about how your function works? I'm not quite a math whiz. What is the significance of the "60", "65" and "300" that you have chosen?

I'm also looking to adapt this to look at 1-hour ago, 2-hours ago, etc... is that possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31014/discussion-between-davmos-and-user2051312)